# Given a basis B, and a transition matrix from B to B', find the basis B'

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a basis $B$ (of a vector space $V$), and a transition matrix $P_{B\to B'}$, is it possible to find the basis $B'$?

I'm working through change of basis, and I can't work out how (or find any information online) on how, or even it's possible.

Comment: Have you Googled the keywords? http://avishek.net/blog/?p=448, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis, http://www.aimath.org/textbooks/beezer/CBsection.html

Comment: The transition matrix is the matrix whose columns are the coordinates of the vectors of $B'$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume first that $P_{B\rightarrow B'}$ means the matrix of:
$$
\mbox{id}:(V,B)\longrightarrow (V,B').
$$
Then $Q=P_{B\rightarrow B'}^{-1}$ is the matrix of:
$$
\mbox{id}:(V,B')\longrightarrow (V,B).
$$
So the columns of $Q$ are the coordinates of the vectors of $B'$ with respect to the basis $B$. 
Knowing the vectors of $B$, you can now compute those of $B'$.

But if $P_{B\rightarrow B'}$ means the matrix of:
$$
\mbox{id}:(V,B)\longrightarrow (V,B')
$$
then its columns are already the coordinates of the vectors of $B'$ with respect to $B$ etc..., so no need to invert it.

Note: I believe the first interpretation is the most universal one.